# Stop sed on windows from changing \r to \r\n

Tags: windows, sed

I'm using sed on windows to delete some superfluous lines in a unix style format (\n line endings). Unfortunately, sed replaces these line endings even in lines it does not change to \r\n. How can I stop sed from doing that?

My sed is a simple sed-for-windows-standalone-exe:

```
C:\dev>sed --version
super-sed version 3.59
based on GNU sed version 3.02.80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how you can do that with sed on Windows but have you tried:

```
unix2dos you_file
sed ...
dos2unix you_file
```

Comment: I know unix2dos...I just don't want to process my files by sed first and then parse them using unix2dos. I want to tell sed to use \n as newline delimiter and not \r\n, although I'm working on a windows machine.

Comment: Here's the problem with this approach: it adds a quite possibily unnecessary layer of processing. I was trying to do some mass changes in a decently big git repo on a Windows machine... every single file being marked as all lines changed is quite annoying, so doing it within sed itself is much nicer.

Answer (score 11):

GNU sed ( http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm ) has the -b option for "binary mode", i. e. not replacing \n with \r\n.

If you use the sed that comes with cygwin then it usually uses the binary mode even without the -b option. Namely, cygwin commands use the input file path to decide whether they should run in text or binary mode, i. e. outputting \r\n or \n: http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-textbinary.html.
As the document says, binary mode is the default for MS-DOS pathnames, and in my experience the filesystems mounted by default are also mounted in binary mode.

Comment: This or @Kokkie shorter version of this should be the accepted answer imho. They actually answer the question instead of mending the problem created. Finally I can use sed to speed up making mass changes working in a git repo on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 5):

If you add the parameter -b you treat the file as a binary file and it won't change your line endings.
The manual states:

```
 -b, --binary

          open files in binary mode (CR+LFs are not processed specially)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but sed doesn't seem to work as you would like, i.e., sed != awk (which is configurable).

I downloaded the [ssed executable](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/ssed/sed-3.62.zip) and the help output did not mention any option for this, as I'm sure you know.

You could try to modify the [source code](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/ssed/sed-3.62.tar.gz), or contacting the authors.

Reading thru the NEWS file in the source code, I found

```
* The s/// command now understands the following escape (in both halves):
\a  an "alert" (BEL)
\f  a form-feed
\n  a newline
\r  a carriage-return
\t  a horizontal tab
\v  a vertical tab
\oNNN   a character with the octal value NNN
\dNNN   a character with the decimal value NNN
\xNN    a character with the hexadecimal value NN
```

Have you tried `s/\r//' as the last command in your script?

I did a quick scan in most of the text files, but didn't find anything that leads me to believe there a cmd-line option that will give what you need.

As you don't want to use unix2dos, as an act of sheerest optimism, I offer the option of using tr to cleanout those pesky '\r's

```
 sed -i -f yourSedScript yourFile
 mv yourFile yourFile.wrk
 tr -d '\015' yourFile.wrk > yourFile
```

Finally, as it seems that if you are editing  Unix files on a windows box, you must be transfering files via 'ftp' or similar to get your Unix to Windows, why not rely on the ftp options to convert line endings?

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not transfering files. I'm editing C++ Builder specific files (.dfm), which have Unix-style newlines although I'm working on a windows machine.

`s/\r//' does not work, since sed will attach \r\n at the end of each line again